# Is there a way to generate multiple documents in my application using the Prawn gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to generate pdfs using the prawn gem. The goal is to create custom pdf's using data submitted through a form. Examples of these could be reports, invoices, birth certificates etc. I have had initial success generating *a* pdf. This one is named "Report".

```
  #Controller
  class TemplatesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_template, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  def show
    @templates = Template.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        pdf = ReportPdf.new
        send_data pdf.render, filename: 'report.pdf', type: 'application/pdf', 
        disposition: "inline"
      end
    end
  end

 #....lots of code

# Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
def template_params
  params.require(:template).permit(:name, :address, :idnumber)
end
end
```

This works and generates a pdf with a template like that below:

```
#My Report.pdf. Similar templates exist for birth certificates deeds, invoices and 
other pdf documents

class ReportPdf < Prawn::Document
  def initialize
    super()
    header
    text_content
  end

  def header
  #Inserts an image in the pdf file and sets its size.
  image "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/logo.jpg", width: 230, height: 75
  end

  def text_content
    bounding_box([0, y_position], :width => 270, :height => 300) do
  
    text "This is a sample report by #{@template.name} who lives at # 
    {@template.address} etc etc"
    end
  end
end
```

Finally, a form I'd like to present to a user:

```
<%=form_with url: templates_path(format: "pdf"), local: true,method: :get do |form| %>

<%= form.label :pdf_type %>
<%= form.select :pdf_type,
options_for_select([
['Report','Report'],
['Birth_certificate','Birth Certificate'],
['Deed','Deed'],
['Title','Title']]),
{}, {class: "form-control" } %> 

<%= form.button "Download", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

As may be seen, the report pdf is 'bound' to a controller action, thus allowing production of one pdf ('report') at the present time. There is no flexibility. To generate a different kind of report I have to manually change the controller code
How do I permit a user select a pdf type from the form and generate the pdf of his choice ?

Answer (score 0):

Just from a RESTful POV, you might be better off using the `create` action to handle the PDF generation. Perhaps change the `form_with` to point to the POST action and then inspect the `pdf_type` param to check the type of report to generate.

Conceptually you're overloading the idea of 'show' for a resource. The PDF doesn't exist yet, so showing it doesn't make much sense. I know you *can* do it like this, but you're really running against Rails and its conventions.

So, in short, move the rendering of the form to your controller's `new` method and handle the generation and sending of the PDF in the `create` method like you currently do with `send_data`.

Edit: I may be misunderstanding what you are trying to achieve, but there's some confusing artefacts in your example - what is the role of `@templates` for instance.

If it's just a matter of selecting the right PDF to generate based on user input you just need a `case` statement or similar, *e.g.*

```
pdf = case template_params[:name]
when 'Report' then ReportPdf.new
when 'Birth_certificate' then BirthCertificatePdf.new
  .. etc ..
end

respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf do
    send_data pdf.render, filename: 'report.pdf', type: 'application/pdf', 
    disposition: "inline"
  end
end
```

You'll have to check what's actually in `template_params`, matching the param value with a case clause that builds out the specific report that you are after.

Does any of this make sense? I don't feel I'm helping. Sorry.

Comment: Your suggestion is logical. My mind skipped over the possibility of a case statement. It appears to be what I need ! Thank you.
So in the 'respond to' block, do I do string interpolation for the filename to recognize the required template  ? It is still pointing to 'report.pdf'
 How would that work in practice ?.
(To answer your question, @template.name etc bring in the user attributes. My model is named Template. I will change it later)

Comment: is the "name" a property of the PDF resource perhaps? e.g. `class ReportPdf < Prawn::Document; def name; "report.pdf"; end` and then refer to in your send_data call (`filename: pdf.name`)  - or something like that

Comment: In your example btw 'report.pdf' is just a string literal - the name of the file as it will appear to the user. It doesn't seem to have any value above and beyond that.

Comment: 'name' is currently an attribute like so:  
Rails g scaffold Template name, address, identitynumber:integer


I will try your recommendation